# When listing child pages run out of memory

Tags: wp-query, pages, child-pages

I am currently having an issue with memory when my site tries to generate a tree of child pages. to my understanding query is too large (WP has 60000 pages)

following is code i am using

```
 ?php global $post;
      wp_list_pages( array(
      'child_of' => $post->ID, // Only pages that are children of the current page
      'depth' => 1 ,   // Only show one level of hierarchy
      'sort_order' => 'asc',
      'title_li' =>$post->post_title
    ));
    ?>
```

Is there any additional arguments i can add to make the query smaller or is there any better way of displaying a list of child pages?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Limit the query... and fetch using AJAX...

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu would you have a suggestion on implementation of ajax as i am very novice to it

Comment: AJAX is good for your case... Begin with it...

Answer (score 1):

[WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) has [Pagination_Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) like `posts_per_page` and `offset` to help you out. Just page the results to limit the query to a more reasonable number per page.

Comment: im not trying to pull all 60000. what im doing is a page that may be located 3 levels into the hierarchy tree  and display a list of all pages that are children of it (10-40 pages)

Comment: Well, this would make your query smaller... Same with date range

Comment: used wp_query in the end thank you very much will post solution now

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any wrong in your code, maybe you should check that whether you can got correct post id via `$post->ID`, sometimes some code before yours changed $post object cause that you can't get it and `wp_list_pages()` will display all pages.

Comment: it displays 50 % of the time and the other 50 i get out of memory error which i think is caused by query checking far too many pages

Comment: Execution time and such things are there...

Comment: No, i'm not saying execution time, like you replied in another answer, you are not trying to pull 60000 results, just 10-40 pages. if the post_id specified to `child_of ` is correct, it should only return the child pages, most time it will not spend more than 1 second.

Comment: <?php global $post;
      wp_list_pages( array(
      'child_of' => $post->ID, // Only pages that are children of the current page
      'depth' => 1 ,   // Only show one level of hierarchy
      'sort_order' => 'asc',
      'title_li' =>$post->post_title
    ));

Comment: `var_dump($post);` before your code, and check it.

Answer (score 0):

To shorten the execution time i ended up using WP_Query as suggested by jgraup

the code to generate list of children is below

```
<?php global $post;
  echo '<p>'. get_the_title().'</p>'; // current post title
  $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post_parent' => $post->ID,'order'   => 'ASC') ); // find all pages with parentId of current page id 
      if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
          echo '<ul>'; 
          while ( $query->have_posts() ) {//loop through results
            $query->the_post();
            echo '<li><a href='. get_page_link($post->ID) .'>' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';//li with link to the page
          }
          echo '</ul>';
          /* Restore original Post Data */
          wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
          // no posts found
        }


    ?>
```